# TCPIP client server communication

Tags: sockets, tcp

How can I change the socket priority by using

```
int setsockopt(int sockfd, int level, int optname,const void *optval, socklen_t optlen);
```

and also help me to understand what is the use of `const void *optval`.

Comment: What part of the documentation didn't you understand?

Comment: what is the difference between optval = 0 and optval =6

Comment: what i understand is based on the optval the priority of the socket is changed while using SO_PRIORITY flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the effect of setting a linux socket - high priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998404/what-is-the-effect-of-setting-a-linux-socket-high-priority)

Comment: I read that also their he mentiond  int optval=7 // valid values are in the range [1,7]  // 1- low priority, 7 - high priority // but low number gets high priority right..?

Comment: In my case im having 3 sockets (flag i used is SO_PRIORITY) for first socket i set optval=1 , second socket optval=4, and for socket thride one i set optval = 6. can you please explain what will happen for each case